# Density of Sequences of Hilbert Spaces and Bochner Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, bochner-spaces

Consider an integer $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $V_{k}, V, H$ be distinct Hilbert spaces with identical inner products and, therefore, the same norms. We have:
$$V_{k},V\subset H$$

In this context, I consider $V_k = \{z\in H \lvert z \in Ker(T_k) \}$ and $V = \{ z\in H \lvert z\in Ker(T) \}$, where $T$ and $T_k$ are continuous functionals from $H$ to some Banach space $L$.

We say a sequence of Hilbert spaces $V_{k}$ is dense in $V$ if for every $v\in V$, a sequence $V_{k}\ni v_{k}\to v$ can be found that converges in norm.

Now, if $V_{k}$ is dense in $V$, can we assert that $L^{2}(0,T,V_{k})$ is dense in $L^{2}(0,T,V)$?

In an attempt to argue this, I consider a function $v\in L^{2}(0,T,V)$. For almost every $t\in[0,T]$, there exists a sequence $v_{k}(t)\in V_{k}$ satisfying:

$$v_{k}(t)\to v(t)$$

This is beacause $\|v(t)\|$ is finite almost everywhere.

Hence, as for almost every t, we have $\|v_{k}(t)\|\leq C\|v(t)\|$, we deduce that $\|v_{k}\|_{L^{2}(0,T,V)}$ is in $L^{2}(0,T,V_{k})$.

So, what I'm really trying to figure out is, can we just go ahead and do pointwise evaluations almost everywhere on a function in $L^{2}(0,T,V)$? Also, does the logic I've laid out above check out, or am I missing something?

Comment: It's unclear what "having the same norms" means. For example, if this means that the spaces $V_k$ are closed subspaces of $V$, then it's hard for proper subspaces to have sequences approaching points in the larger, etc. Do you actually mean something like a colimit? As might occur for Sobolev spaces or similar? Can you be more precise about your set-up? :)

Comment: You can't just check pointwise limits, $L^2$ is a notion of uniformity that is very different from pointwise convergence. Besides your definition is probably not finished, since if $V'\subseteq V$ then you have from $V_k\to V$ that also $V_k\to V'$. I am unsure if you want this property.

Comment: @paulgarrett It appears all spaces are viewed as subspaces of some larger Hilbert space $H$. When OP says "having the same norm" my understanding is that they get the scalar product coming from the restriction $V_k\subseteq H$. The $V_k$ are not necessarily in $V$ (they are in $H$), but even if they were this would not be an obstacle to getting $V_k\to V$, even if all $V_k$ are proper (example: $\ell^2(\{1,...,k\})\subset \ell^2(\Bbb N)$).

Comment: Indeed, in this specific context, we have that $H=H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)^2$. 

Also, $V_k$ is defined as the kernel of $T_k$, and $V$ is the kernel of $T$. Here, $T$ and $T_k$ are linear operators mapping from $H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)^2$ to $L^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: @s.harp, I was under the impression that if we denote $E =  \{ t \in [0,T] \ | \  \|f(t)\| = \infty \}$, we have that $\mu(E)=0$, then this would imply that pointwise evaluation of $f(t)$ is available almost everywhere.

Comment: Yes, but thats not what I meant. You are checking that there is a sequence of functions that converges pointwise, but you need to check $L^2$ convergence. Another problem is that your functions $v_k$ are also only pointwise defined and its not clear why they are in $L^2$

Comment: Well yes you are right the sequence is only pointwise thus I can use the dominated convergence theorem, Thanks for the help :)